# Appendix vs Supplement

Tags: publications, terminology, supporting-information

I'm surprised that this hasn't been asked before. What's the difference between Appendices and Supplements?

Also, btw, what is the most widely approved version of "Supplements"? Is it "Supplemental Materials" or "Supplementary Materials"? My field is machine learning & computer vision, if it's relevant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In most (all?) machine learning & computer vision conferences:

- Appendices = more PDF pages.
- Supplements = additional non-PDF content, e.g. code and data.

"Supplementary Materials" is most commonly used in my experience. I've never read "Supplemental Materials".

Comment: Supplemental material can also be PDF files with data tables, additional examples and so on. They should not be required to understand the article, but useful for the interested reader.

Comment: @allo true, I'm not sure how to phrase properly but I guess you get the idea. Appendix is some paper extension while supplementary materials are some extra data/code/etc. "They should not be required to understand the article, but useful for the interested reader" same for appendices. Hard to find a good phrasing that applies for all cases.

Answer (score 6):

The field is almost always relevant to questions like this, so I defer to the [answer by Franck Dernoncourt](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/200364/17254) for your case. This is just to give a flavor of how things can much vary. In physics (journals), I would expect

- Appendices = additional material that is presented within the article itself (for example, inside the article PDF), but outside the main text.
- "Supplements" = ["information that is useful to a subset of readers but is not essential to comprehend the article’s main results"](https://journals.aps.org/prb/authors). The most typical form is a separate PDF with details or additional analysis, but it can also be in the form of code, data, multimedia files etc. or some combination. Many publishers have lists of supported file formats.

I've seen all combinations of "Supplemental/Supplementary Information/Material". What is standard varies by publication venue. If there is a print version of the journal, the appendices would be printed, but supplements would not. Sometimes this is reflected in them being called "Electronic Supplementary Material" or similar.